# Label with comma's and numbers into a: "List<int>", how?

Tags: c#, android, list, xamarin, int

I made a label with text: 'Label1.Text = "1,2,3,4,5";'. I want to seperate all numbers and then I want to add it in a: 'List'. I need to use a for loop or foreach, because I select some values and those values will go in the: 'Label1.Text', and those need to be add to the: 'List'.

I can't find any right code for this. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use [`.Split(',')`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method which will Returns a string
  array that contains the substrings in this instance that are
  delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode character
  array.
- Now you are having an array of strings. But your requirement is
  List so you need to convert each element in the resultant array
  into an integer to form the `List<int>`.

The whole scenario can be done by using the following code:

```
string labelText=Label1.Text; // Let it be "1,2,3,4,5";
List<int> inputList = labelText.Split(new char[]{','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                               .Select(x=> int.Parse(x))
                               .ToList();
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9MgYQv)

Comment: I already found this code, but i thought I need to use add, and the php code into c# is working btw.

Comment: So I don't have to use add?

Comment: This code isn't working. I need to add every number apart. I get no result in my listview.

Comment: @Test There's a missing closing parenthesis at the end of the line with `.Split()`.

Comment: Indeed but I knew that

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'StringSplitOptions' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'StringSplitOptions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Check whether `)` is there before `.Select(x=>` I have added a working example

Comment: Oh sorry, I closed it at the end

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = Label1.Text;
List<int> list = str.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
```